# Jazzy: zsh: no matches found: --documentation=./*.md

Tags: shell, zsh, documentation, documentation-generation, jazzy

I'm using [jazzy](https://github.com/realm/jazzy) and it seems to not want to include all of the markdown files in the rendered documentation pages.
For example,

> jazzy --xcodebuild-arguments -scheme,MyCustomSchemeName --documentation=./*.md

produces the following output:

> zsh: no matches found: --documentation=./*.md

What could be the issue here? I'm trying to avoid shell expansion when using this command:

> jazzy --documentation Full/Path_ToDoc.docc/**.md --xcodebuild-arguments -scheme,MyCustomSchemeName

As this produces the following output:

> Leftover unused command-line text: ["Full/Path_ToDoc.docc/File2.md", "Full/Path_ToDoc.docc/File1.md"]

Relevant GitHub issues:
https://github.com/realm/jazzy/issues/1295

https://github.com/realm/jazzy/issues/850

The goal is to include all of the markdown files in the directory to render. If I use just this command:

> jazzy --documentation Full/Path_ToDoc.docc/**.md --xcodebuild-arguments -scheme,MyCustomSchemeName

It actually generates the documentation, but omits 2 other files that are stored in the folder due to the shell expansion.

Comment: In general, if you write something like `foo=*.bar`, **zsh** tries filename expansion and searches for files starting with `foo=` and ending with `.bar`. However you don't want to do filename expansion by zsh, but want it done by **jazzy**, not zsh. Hence you need to pass the wildcard literally to jazzy, for instance by writing `--documentation=./\*.md`.

Comment: I found a solution by using the format I've listed in my answer. If you'd like to accept this answer, please post it as an answer and not comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting solved the issue:

> jazzy --xcodebuild-arguments -scheme,MyScheme
> --documentation='Full/PathToDoc.docc/*.md'